# Theory Language- What is the best way to convert a regular expression to an automata?

Tags: automaton

I have a question about how to convert a regular expression to aan automata? I hear about the Gluskov algorithm but i couldn't find a right document about it.

Example: i have an regular expression like `(a*|b*) U (a*a|c*)*` and i want to convert in a automata with a simple algorithm.

Please help me

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: This sounds like homework.  Even if it isn't, we don't do the work for you, and we don't answer opinion based "what's the best way" questions.

Comment: No i just ask about the Gluskov algorithm and the way how to use it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is most likely a homework question for which the OP has shown no effort.